# JGrowl set theme from css

Tags: jgrowl

I have some code using Jquery Growl function. But I want to customize it to something like that - https://codepen.io/killerek/pen/qqdZJp

I'm using a code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $.jGrowl('{$message}');
</script>
```

I wanted to use my own css code by editing this line as follows but didn't work for me.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $.jGrowl('{$message}','{theme: 'default'});
</script>
```

Any other ideas? Thanks

Comment: Is this the write code pen? I’m not seeing jGrowl used in it. It would also be helpful to share your CSS for styling the theme.

Comment: I want ot use it on mybb forum in combination with a plugin from this site https://www.mybboost.com/thread-release-inline-success-messages-2-1

Comment: I don't know anything about the mybb usage of jGrowl, but I can point you to the example in the jGrowl repository with a custom theme. I've provided an answer below referencing that code and providing some code. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

The key to using the `theme` option is the CSS definition, as `theme` just maps to a CSS class.

In the [jGrowl repository](https://github.com/stanlemon/jGrowl) there is an example folder that demonstrates this behavior:

Check out the CSS here:
https://github.com/stanlemon/jGrowl/blob/master/examples/jgrowl.html#L16-L19

```css
.jGrowl .manilla {
    background-color:       #FFF1C2;
    color:                  navy;
}
```

And the javascript here:
https://github.com/stanlemon/jGrowl/blob/master/examples/jgrowl.html#L95-L120

```
$.jGrowl("Here is a custom theme.", {
    theme:  'manilla'
});
```

Notice `theme` of `manilla` maps to `.jGrowl .manilla`.

For your situation you would need a similar declaration `.jGrowl .default`.